# How to debug a coldfusion function defined in a component?

Tags: function, coldfusion, components, cfc

Is there any way that I can access a component's function through url request for debugging purpose just like we access function in php frameworks like CodeIgniter?

Thanks!

Comment: By debugging do you mean fixing something that is not doing what you think it should be doing, of simply looking at what is in the component?

Comment: Thanks for response @DanBracuk. Debugging means something inside a function is not working as expected. To check that I can put a cfdump inside that function and access that method/function directly through url.

Problem generally arises when I put cfdump to debug any database query inside function, I get a response that function is of type 'struct' and returned data is not of type 'struct' and thus I cannot see whatever cfdump has dumped.

Comment: Generally, when debugging, I use cfmail to email me the results of a query.

Comment: cfmail is fine, but doesn't seems as best practice. Isn't it?

Comment: (Update) @R.Pandey - Can you please post a small example that demonstrates the problem? Usually what you described should work if "output" isn't suppressed ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this,

> Problem generally arises when I put cfdump to debug any database query
>   inside function, I get a response that function is of type 'struct'
>   and returned data is not of type 'struct' and thus I cannot see
>   whatever cfdump has dumped.

The answer is to set the abort attribute of your cfdump tag to true.

Comment: I did that too. Still don't get anything displayed as calling function don't get anything in return after addition of abort attribute.

Comment: Are you creating an object anywhere?